# Custom RoleProvider using session

Tags: c#, .net, roleprovider, asp.net-membership

I was considering using the custom MembershipProvider / RoleProviders.

Unfortunately, the security layer we currently have requires some session stuff being set. So, when the IsUserInRole() method is called, the Session object is always null, due to the Session stuff being all prepopulated.

Any suggestions on how I would be able to work around this, and retain the use of the Session based security model we have?

(I didn't write it, and I have got to use it).

Any help greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might need some code on this.

It's almost certain you will need read access to your session as it sounds like some authorisation flag is kept there?

This might rule this out for you, have a read of this [forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/967758/1214615.aspx), note ScottGu's answers

Comment: hey dove, thanks very much, i've had a look at that, was just hoping for a magic way of getting read access to the session (i am also aware that the session is set later, so it was always going to be very unlikely, but worth an ask :) )