# Extending the RoleProvider GetRolesForUser()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider, asp.net-roles

The `GetRolesForUser()` method in the `RoleProvider` takes the user login name and returns the list of roles for that user. But in my application this is not enough, I need a few more pieces of information to be able to get the user's roles.

How can I get this extra information into the method?

I have it in the `Session`, but I found out that `Session` is not available in the `RoleProvider`.

What I had in mind was putting this extra info in some class that extends `MembershipUser`, assuming I can get to it inside the `RoleProvider`. But I don't know how to create the `CustomMembershipUser` and make it part of the `MembershipProvider`. Is this even possible?

The easy way out would be [using cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425731/custom-roleprovider-using-session), but I'm trying to keep away from it.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need more than just the user name. Surely a user name always uniquely identifies a user in any credential store, that's why Microsoft designed the API that way.

Comment: Because the application supports several "services" and a user can have access to more than one service, with a different set of roles in each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem: using a cookie to store any extra information needed by the `RoleProvider`.

Comment: Just a note: this works but causes the unnecessary overhead of a cookie -- HttpContext.Current.Items is a less expensive place to store the information..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can store and retrieve things in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` array, that IS available in the `RoleProvider`, unlike Session.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just wanted to suggest using specific roles per service. So instead of having something like Administrator, Manager, and User you'd have Service1_Administrator, Service2_Administrator, Service1_Manager, Service2_Manager, Service1_User, Service2_User, etc.

How did you solve it?

Comment: I solved it by adding the service identifier to a cookie and then access it in the Role Provider to get the correct roles.